# Jar file run only in main directories

Tags: java, jar

I have developed my program in Eclipse and I exported a Jar file. Something strange happens for me when I put jar file on main directories like C: or D: jar file run successfully but when I put it in other places and sub directories, double-click do not do anything. Even I tried to run it in command-line and nothing happens! Anybody knows what is the reason?! If it has error no where should work!

Comment: Are there spaces in the directory name?

Comment: you need to improve this explanation my friend

Comment: What is the error message when you execute the file in the command-line?

Comment: To sum up, give us the exact input and output of cmd, AND, whether or not you have administrator privileges.

Comment: I export my program into Runnable Jar File and I only got some warning during exportation. I am using Sqlite. When I put it on main drive it works great but when I put anywhere else it does not run and does not give any error. I tried to run in Cmd but no error! Input is C:/software/project.jar no output. If I put file in C: it run without any problem!

Comment: Even it does not come up on other Drive. Only on the C: which my windows has been installed. Strange! What do you think?

Comment: What is your program supposed to be doing? Are you perhaps using any hard-coded files inside your code, that only exist at the root directory of your C drive?